# Wordpress AJAX logout script issues

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a function that needs to log a user out of `WordPress` after a certain condition is met. The function `logout_check()` is called from another function.  I've tried using `wp_logout()` after  the `IF` statement, however `WordPress` comes back with *'headers already sent ...'*.

So, I'm trying to logout using `javascript`.

With the help of this forum I've written some code.  I know the criteria of the test `change_check()` is met to logout, but it doesn't look like the `javascript` is executed.  There are 2 parts, `functions.php` and `customAjaxLogout.js`.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
/* ================== CLIENT LOGOUT CHECK FUNCTION ================== */
function logout_check(){
    $my_redirect = home_url();
    $my_quit = change_check(); // this DB function returns 'quit' / 'ok'
    if ($my_quit == 'quit'){
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-ajax-logout', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/customAjaxLogout.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_localize_script('custom-ajax-logout', 'ajax_object',
            array(
                'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                'home_url' => $my_redirect,
                'logout_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-logout-nonce'),
            )
        );
        exit();
    }
    else{
        wp_redirect($my_redirect);
        exit();
    }
}


/* ================== AJAX LOGOUT FUNCTION ================== */
function custom_ajax_logout_func(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-logout-nonce', 'ajaxsecurity' );
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_logout();
    ob_clean();
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_ajax_logout', 'custom_ajax_logout_func');
```

customAjaxLogout.js

```
$(document).ready( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'action': 'custom_ajax_logout',
            'ajaxsecurity': ajax_object.logout_nonce
        },
        success: function(r){
            // When the response comes back
            window.location = ajax_object.home_url;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So where does the execution stop? If the Ajax call is not triggered, then is the script `customAjaxLogout.js` actually loaded? This is very basic debugging stuff.

Comment: I'm sorry, new to javascript. I know the IF statement is entered (put a redirect in there so I know its entered when the 'quit' is met. However with the code above, the user is not logged out, so not sure the JS code is even executed or written correctly.  Thanks

Comment: Check your browser's network console tab to see if the script is loaded at all.

Comment: @Michael - I don't see it loaded at all, thats why I'm thinking I have a code issue in the JS or calling the JS.  In regards to when the function is called, it is on a POST of a page.   The check is called in a shortcode in a field on a page.  I was trying to call the JS just inline with the rest of the code, perhaps that doesnt work.

Comment: You might have to try to include your scripts in the footer, then. Because if you load them in the header (which is default), it should be too late by the time your shortcode gets parsed.